# fopen without fclose in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

What happens if i open a file using `fopen` some *n* number of times without calling `fclose` on it?

Any buffer overrun issues may arise?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Don't capitalise standard C function names. C is case-sensitive.

Comment: Are you asking about opening *the same* file multiple times?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you continue to `fopen` without `fclose` then eventually your future calls to `fopen` will start to fail.  There are a limited number of file descriptors available to your program.

[See this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184345/fopen-problem-too-many-open-files).

Comment: Just for further information, I recollect from the early days of DOS that you could set the number of available files that could be opened as an environment variable - up to a point, of course. I believe the default may have been 25, and for some apps definitely needed to be set higher since some of these were used by the OS itself.

Comment: Yes, exactly the same happened.The fopen failed after some 1000 calls.I closed it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You waste underlying file handles. Please close any files you open, in a timely fashion, as to avoid this leak of resources.

Comment: Also, calling `fclose` ensures that any data written to the file is not lost in case the application aborts.

Comment: You make it sound like there's a giant global pool of file handles that all computers across the world share.  Please recycle your file handles. :)

Comment: @jdizzle: rationing starts next week, grab all you can now!

Answer (score 4):

If you continue opening files without closing them then you will run out of file descriptors at some point, either at the application level or the OS level, and all further attempts to open a file will fail.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from wasting file descriptors for the process as others answered, you would also *waste memory* since each file stream manages in/out buffers that are allocated internally by `libc`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you don't want to leak file descriptors. But it *is* ok to have a single file open multiple times. The file descriptors are independent and will not interfere with each other (assuming you are just reading and not writing to the file).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f1 = fopen("/tmp/foo.txt", "rb");
    FILE* f2 = fopen("/tmp/foo.txt", "rb");
    FILE* f3 = fopen("/tmp/foo.txt", "rb");
    FILE* f4 = fopen("/tmp/foo.txt", "rb");

    char buf1[32] = { 0, };
    char buf2[32] = { 0, };
    char buf3[32] = { 0, };
    char buf4[32] = { 0, };

    fread(buf1, 1, sizeof(buf1) - 1, f1);
    fread(buf2, 1, sizeof(buf2) - 1, f2);
    fread(buf3, 1, sizeof(buf3) - 1, f3);
    fread(buf4, 1, sizeof(buf4) - 1, f4);

    printf("buf1 = '%s'\n", buf1);
    printf("buf2 = '%s'\n", buf2);
    printf("buf3 = '%s'\n", buf3);
    printf("buf4 = '%s'\n", buf4);

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);
    fclose(f4);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives output like:

```
$ ./fopen 
buf1 = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ0123456789a'
buf2 = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ0123456789a'
buf3 = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ0123456789a'
buf4 = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ0123456789a'
```