# IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files -Python, Windows

Tags: windows, io

I'm using Python on Windows to split a large file (few GBs) into many smaller files. The file is splitted by line's content, so I need all the small files to be opened in the same time, and the content to be written into them.

I got `IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` when trying to open one of the files, and according to the debugger there are already 507 open files.

Is there a way to raise the maximum allowed open files?

I read about the `ulimit` option in macOS, but couldn't find an equivalent option on Windows.

Also- why do I get this error after 507 files? Is this specifically the maximum?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need all the files to be opened at the same time? Why not split the big file in memory and then write out the smaller ones sequentially?

Comment: The large file (which actually might be few large files one after the other) might be *very* large (overall including all files- few GBs)

Comment: please have a look at this Q/A, your question seems to be a duplicate of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read large text files in Python, line by line without loading it in to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory)

Comment: I know exactly how to read the file, my problem is with writing it to other files simultaneously, it's not related to the answer in the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fopen problem - too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184345/fopen-problem-too-many-open-files)

Comment: I agree it is a similar question, but the question in the link doesn't give a good solution @stovfl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently 512 is the maximum in python. 
I found the solution here- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28212496/8875017

```
import win32file
win32file._setmaxstdio(2048)
```